# How can I add more ports with enough power to run six USB webcams on my laptop at the same time?

Tags: laptop, usb, camera

I want to run six cameras in my laptop at once (recording video at once).

The issue I faced is that there are not enough USB ports.  So I bought a USB hub which didn't work well because it divided the USB bandwidth between the cameras attached to that hub.

So now I am looking for another way to add extra USB slots to my laptop.
Or connect my desktop pc to my laptop somehow, so I can run the program on my laptop using USB ports from my desktop PC.
Or any other any other way to achieve the final goal.

Comment: You already said more hubs worked. So what is your actual question? There is not unlimited bandwidth on your computer though.

Comment: Can you just use your desktop PC to run the program instead? You can add USB ports through use of a PCI card. Google `USB 3.0 pci card` to see examples

Comment: @music2myear Hello thanks for you response, sir i said it divided the bandwidth which meant not working at all although i have edited my question eliminate confusion.

Comment: @MC10 sir by using desktop pc my whole project will become completely immovable stick at only one place which i dont want and cant afford to be happen as well. It need to be on laptop or anyother movable device.

Comment: @YounusPaperwala I see, but you mentioned you wanted to somehow connect the desktop's USB ports to the laptop while running the project. This would make the laptop immovable while the project runs. Is it possible to run the project on the desktop and copy the relevant files/data to the laptop afterwards?

Comment: @MC10 sir regarding that desktop thing i was planning for the last resort as if i dont find any way and transferring complete project to my desktop will effect negatively as my laptop is much more fast in processing speed as compared to my desktop so i thought using only it's port would be enough if i dont find any other option.

Comment: @MC10 other than that sir i am trying to something like live streaming project so transferring video files afterward wont help as it needs real time recording and uploading to the server.

Answer (score 3):

Video is a bandwidth-intensive workload. USB video from cheap cameras even more so, as they are designed to have the host do the majority of the encoding work.

So for 6 cameras to work at the same time, you must provide enough USB bandwidth from the cameras into your machine to transport those 6 streams at the same time - this might be a challenge, as the majority of the cheap cams will be on USB 2.0 only but nearly saturate it.

In addition to that you need to make sure, that your laptop's CPU is powerfull enough to deal with 6 streams at the same time, cheap USB cams have a notoriously high CPU usage.

I suggest you investigate using IP based cameras instead of USB-based ones: Those do the compression work inside the camera and you can easily get a lot of good quality streams over a single gigabit port. A 12Mbit/s h.264 HD stream can transport a quality not many cameras actually can achieve, and you can get a theoretical max of 80 of those over a single gigabit port with a $25 switch.

Comment: That is the only sane answer. USB camera's are, in most cases, absolute shit. Even if the camera is decent the accompanying drivers are usually extremely low quality and, in many cases, get in each others way because they have a tendency to assume they are the only high USB bandwidth user (as most people will only have 1 camera) on the system and hog the USB controller, thereby blocking the other camera's.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your suggestion, but the problem is i have already bought usb cams as i didnt have prior knowledge regarding these differences and issues, and as being a university student i cant afford much to buy those cameras yet again so is there any way to convert these usb cameras into ip based camera or any other trick? Thank you

Comment: No, there isn't @YounusPaperwala. While you may not like the solution, this is the correct solution. Your current method is untenable, as you've already found, and the correct solution is to change methods, or recognize that what you want is not currently possible given your limitations (low budget).

Comment: I got the point i am currently in the wrong direction which will only lead me to the dead end.

Comment: Can you suggest me cheap ways to get ip cameras either by making it through arduino or rasberry pi or converting my usbcams into ip camera... Anything.... Btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use a USB-3 hub will have the same problem as well (and CPU for the video). The best will even follow the above answer: IP camera (o the conventional and cheaper DVR kit)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10243723/4122311

> The problem is not how many you can discover. On a single USB bus,
>   ~127 could be possible.
>
> But, a USB bus can only transfer a limited amount of bytes per second.
>   So if you want to use more then one, you have to calculate the amount
>   of bandwidth you have for the video stream.
>
> Example : A USB bus normally can deliver realistically ~35 MB/s.
>   640*480*2 bytes per pixel => 614400 bytes per frame. @30 FPS this is
>   ~17 MB/s, so you can use 2 cameras simultaneously with this setup.